# FullCalendar: Passing null in start

Tags: javascript, null, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in one of my projects. The json events contain many entries and in few of the entries the start date is null. I want those events to not be visible in the calendar. But right now, those events are visible in the current date. Is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: just do not send the json with start date as null, else use http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: right. I was hoping if there is any other way it is handled in fullcalendar itself. Anyways thanks for your inputs

Comment: the link that i had shared earlier does resolve your problem through fullcalendar pre defined methods eventRender: function (event, element) {//check for event.start here }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. Filter them out with a custom [event source function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) or change them in [eventDataTransform](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/).

Of the two, `eventDataTransform` is usually easier unless you are already using a function for your event source.

Garima's suggestion of using `eventRender` won't work since FC throws an error before it get's to eventRender.

#### eventDataTransform Method

```
eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
    if (eventData.start == null) { //catches null or undef
        eventData.start = moment("1975","yyyy"); //some time that won't be used
        eventData.end = moment("1975","yyyy");
    }
    return eventData;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/Lh5vp0bz/2/)

If that's too hacky for you, do something like:

```
eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
    if (eventData.start == null) { //catches null or undef
        eventData.start = moment(); //set it to a valid time
        eventData.hidden = true; //flag it as invalid (this will be a custom property of the event)
    }
    return eventData;
}
```

And then make the `eventRender` callback return false when `event.hidden === true`.

But that's a bit more work and probably not necessary.